# JSON array to html table

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8

How do I handle an error with the mondogdb driver on an insert? This is an example they provide on inserting a document.

```
collection.insertOne(doc, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
      /* How I would handle using jdbc
      if(result.succeed()){
       //System.out.println("Inserted");
      }else{
       //System.out.println("Did not insert, please try again!");
      }
      */
    }
});
```

Lets say the insert fails how to handle the error. I looked inside the result object to see if there is a 'succeed' or 'error' type methods like in a jdbc, but I can't find anything. I need to handle a success different than a fail, for example in a success I need to return a message the insert was successful, but in the error I need to return it was unsuccessful.

Comment: what does that Throwable t doing there ? Is there any use for it?

Comment: I am unsure. This is the way the documentation says to implement it, but does provide a reason for it just that "If the operation failed for any reason then the t contains the Throwable reason for the failure." It does not state though how to find out if it did fail.(http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/getting-started/quick-tour/)

Comment: _I need to handle a success different than a fail_  and _If the operation failed for any reason then the t contains the Throwable reason for the failure_. Seems you have what you need.

Comment: But what would I do with the t object? I tried to check if t==null, but it did not work. From my database though I could see the write was successful.

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB javadoc (http://javadox.com/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.0/com/mongodb/async/SingleResultCallback.html), `t` will be `null` when the operation completed normally.